# Null Pointer Exception on custom pageradapter

Tags: android, exception, fragment, adapter

The code below is for my adapter for viewpager.

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.androidquery.AQuery;

    public class ViewPagerAdapter2 extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] image1;
    String[] description;


    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ViewPagerAdapter2(Context context, String[] image1,String[] description) {
        this.context = context;
        this.image1 = image1;
        this.description=description;


    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


        TextView des;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider, container,
                false);
        des = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.slider_des);
        des.setText(description[position]);
         AQuery aq = new AQuery(itemView);
         aq.id(R.id.imageView1).image(image1[position]);

         ((ViewPager) container).removeView(itemView);



        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return description.length;

    }

}
```

The code for my fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.home, container, false);

        new getFromWebService().execute();
        viewPager1 = (ViewPager) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter1= new ViewPagerAdapter2(mLinearLayout.getContext(),image,title);
        viewPager1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        //ListView list = (ListView) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        //Onadapter listadapter = new Onadapter(getActivity(),id,label,title,image,hrs,posted_date);
        //list.setAdapter(listadapter);

        return mLinearLayout;

    }
```

My logcat output:

```
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lyfcha/com.lyfcha.TestMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at com.lyfcha.ViewPagerAdapter2.getCount(ViewPagerAdapter2.java:69)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:432)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at com.lyfcha.Home1.onCreateView(Home1.java:56)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5216)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2083)
07-31 16:27:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1364):     ... 11 more
```

What ive done:
1. Obtained required data from json in String arrays. 
2. ive written an adapter for the viewpager to feed contents to it.

Where i have run into problem:

Application throws Null Pointer Exception, in onCreateView of my fragment stating that getCount of my adapter throws NPE. i am sure that the string array's length isn't null (tested in display window in debug perspective).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show us where are you populating or initialising `title`.

Comment: title is declared as a global variable....its size defined in the class where the json array is received, and values inserted in a loop from data received in json . i can assure you that there is nothing wrong with the String array! it contains values as desired!

Comment: If it's been populated in another thread, you should consider adding your adapter after the thread is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fill the Adapter from the AsyncTask you use to get the data. Since `getFromWebService` is executing in a different thread, the line

```
adapter1= new ViewPagerAdapter2(mLinearLayout.getContext(),image,title);
```

will still not have the data from the other Thread. So, solution is to move the following lines:

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.home, container, false);

        viewPager1 = (ViewPager) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter1= new ViewPagerAdapter2(mLinearLayout.getContext(),image,title);
        viewPager1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

to the `onPostExecute()` method of your AsyncTask `getFromWebService`

Comment: i dont think that would be an issue because, after getFromWebService is executed it has as intended inserted values to String arrays that ive declared globally! Ive checked each of the variables for thier values, there is no mistake in that part. ive used the values after the AsyncTask has done its task

Comment: The problem I see is that you will not wait for `getFromWebService` to execute (it is in a separate thread), so `description` will be null if `getFromWebService` is in a separate thread.

Comment: Thank you ! i was so stupid not to think in that way! such a silly mistake! thanks a lot !